# How to use dense_rank and rangeBetween on timestamp value?

Tags: pyspark

In Pyspark, I am trying to use dense_rank() to group rows into the same group based on the userId and the time value.

Here is my inital dataframe :

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|              userId|           BeginTime|             EndTime|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|                   A|2021-02-09 15:56:...|2021-02-09 15:56:...|
|                   A|2021-02-09 15:57:...|2021-02-09 15:57:...|
|                   A|2021-02-09 15:58:...|2021-02-09 15:58:...|
|                   B|2021-02-05 13:16:...|2021-02-05 13:16:...|
|                   B|2021-02-05 13:16:...|2021-02-05 13:16:...|
|                   B|2021-02-05 18:27:...|2021-02-05 18:37:...|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

One row represents one action made by one user and gives the startDate and the endDate of each action. I want to gather actions that were made in succession, so if the duration between two action is more than 1 hour, I consider these two actions where not made in succession.

So here is what I expect :

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+
|              userId|           BeginTime|             EndTime| sequence|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+
|                   A|2021-02-09 15:56:...|2021-02-09 15:56:...|        1|
|                   A|2021-02-09 15:57:...|2021-02-09 15:57:...|        1|
|                   A|2021-02-09 15:58:...|2021-02-09 15:58:...|        1|
|                   B|2021-02-05 13:16:...|2021-02-05 13:16:...|        1|
|                   B|2021-02-05 13:16:...|2021-02-05 13:16:...|        1|
|                   B|2021-02-05 18:27:...|2021-02-05 18:37:...|        2|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+
```

I try to use dense_rank() and rangeBetween in my Window like this :

```
w_rank = (Window
.partitionBy("userId")
.orderBy(col("BeginTime").cast("timestamp").cast("long"))
.rangeBetween(0,3600 )
df = df.withColumn('sequence', dense_rank().over(w_rank))
```

But i have this error :

```
AnalysisException : Window Frame specifiedwindowframe(RangeFrame, currentrow$(), 3600) must match the required frame specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, unboundedpreceding$(), currentrow$());
```

I am quite new with pyspark so if anyone could help me on this one I'll be very grateful. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I manage to find something that works for my case, I post my answer here in case it will help someone :

```
w = Window.partitionBy('userId').orderBy(col("BeginTime"))
df = df.withColumn('duration_between_series', col('BeginTime').cast('long') - lag(col('EndTime').over(w) )
.withColumn('rank', dense_rank().over(w))
.withColumn('sequence_temp', when(col('rank')==1, 1).when(col('duration_between_series')>3600, col('rank')).otherwise(None))
.withColumn('sequence', last('sequence_temp', True).over(w.rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize, 0))).drop('sequence_temp', 'duration_between_series')
```

Output :

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+---------+
|              userId|           BeginTime|             EndTime|     rank| sequence|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+---------+
|                   A|2021-02-09 15:56:...|2021-02-09 15:56:...|        1|        1|
|                   A|2021-02-09 15:57:...|2021-02-09 15:57:...|        2|        1|
|                   A|2021-02-09 15:58:...|2021-02-09 15:58:...|        3|        1|
|                   B|2021-02-05 13:16:...|2021-02-05 13:16:...|        1|        1|
|                   B|2021-02-05 13:16:...|2021-02-05 13:16:...|        2|        1|
|                   B|2021-02-05 18:27:...|2021-02-05 18:37:...|        3|        3|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+---------+
```

the column sequence is not exactly like what I expected but as much as I have different values for each group, I am fine with that :)